# understanding gpu usage huggingface classification

Tags: python, gpu, huggingface-transformers

I am building a classifier using huggingface and would like to understand the line `Total train batch size (w. parallel, distributed & accumulation) = 64` from below

```
 Num examples = 7000
  Num Epochs = 3
  Instantaneous batch size per device = 4
  Total train batch size (w. parallel, distributed & accumulation) = 64
  Gradient Accumulation steps = 16
  Total optimization steps = 327
```

i have 7000 rows of data, i have defined epochs to be 3 and  `per_device_train_batch_size = 4` and  `per_device_eval_batch_size= 16`. I also get that `Total optimization steps = 327` - (7000*3/64)

But I am not clear about `Total train batch size (w. parallel, distributed & accumulation) = 64`. Does it mean that there are 16 devices as 16*4(`Instantaneous batch size per device = 4`) comes to 64?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the variable used for printing that summary is this one: https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/src/transformers/trainer.py#L1211.

The total train batch size is defined as `train_batch_size * gradient_accumulation_steps * world_size`, so in your case `4 * 16 * 1 = 64`. `world_size` is always 1 except when you are using a TPU/training in parallel, see https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/src/transformers/training_args.py#L1127.